# Are alphabetic values entered into a number input saved by ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For the following, I had a few questions in terms of what AngularJS compiler is doing so I can better understand what is happening behind the scenes.

```
        <label>
          Calories Needed :<input type="number" name="input" min="0" class="input" ng-model="calories"><br>
        </label>

        <div>
            <span style="font-size:18px;color:red;" ng-show="userForm.input.$error.number">
                Enter a valid number.
            </span>
        </div>
```

I have an input asking to enter a number and if what the user entered is not a number then with the ng-show directive, an error message. My question is even though the error message is showing, does that mean what the user entered is stored in the 'calories' variable regardless if it wasn't a number? I feel like it still saves whatever the user entered in the variable. Just wanted to get a better understanding of what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

No, Angular does not store the value in `calories` until it is a valid number. An easy way to see this is to show a binding for calories in the view as an example.

So:

```
<label>
    Calories Needed :<input type="number" name="input" min="0" class="input" ng-model="calories"><br>
    {{ calories }}
</label>
```

You will see that the calories variable will only be assigned the value typed in by the user when it is valid. If you had `min="5"` in your example, then `calories` would not be assigned a value unless it was 5 or greater.

I have created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NZJbSFPlKJOSYtlZbQBn?p=preview) to show this. You will see that `calories` is undefined until the value entered is >= 5.